# Collection/business object clarification

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've just read couple topics on that forum and decided to ask directly the experts about whether what i have below it's more like collection of class Variation or it's more like business object. Is it correct or should i move everything from class Variations directly to class Variation.

I have class named:

```
 Class Variation
Implements IComparable(Of Variation)
           #Region "Properties"
        Property Name As String
        Property Position As SByte
#End Region

#Region "Constructors"
        Sub New()
            MyBase.New(New VariationDAL)
        End Sub
        Sub New(pId As Integer)
            MyBase.New(New VariationDAL)
            Id = pId
        End Sub
        Sub New(pName As String)
            MyBase.New(New VariationDAL)
            Name = pName
        End Sub

Public Function CompareTo(pother As Variation) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Variation).CompareTo    
            Return String.Compare(Me.Position, pother.Position)
        End Function
        Public Function FindPredicate(ByVal pvariation As Variation) As Predicate(Of Variation)
            Return Function(pvariation2 As Variation) pvariation.Id = pvariation2.Id
        End Function
        Public Function FindPredicateByUserId(ByVal pvariation As String) As Predicate(Of Variation)
            Return Function(pvariation2 As Variation) pvariation = pvariation2.Id
        End Function

    End Class
```

Then i use below class to store collection of above class:

```
Public Class Variations
        Implements IDisposable

        Public Collection As List(Of Variation)

        Sub New()
            Collection = New List(Of Variation)
        End Sub

        Public Function AddToCollection(ByVal variation As Variation) As Boolean
            If variation.Position <> 100 And variation.Name = "23333" Then
                Collection.Add(variation)
            End If
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Sub RemoveFromCollection(index As Integer)
            If Not IsNothing(Collection.Item(index)) Then
                Collection.RemoveAt(index)
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub SortByPosition()
            Collection.Sort()
        End Sub

        Public Sub RemoveFromCollectionX(ByVal variation As Variation)
            For Each item In Collection
                If item.Name = variation.Name And item.Position = variation.Position Then
                    Collection.Remove(item)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End Sub

        Private Sub ReorderCollection()
            '...
        End Sub

'other methods related to collection manipulation

End Class
```

Comment: `Variations` looks more like a class of  optional helper methods.  It is not a collection class - it does not implement an Item/indexer property, nor an Add method.  Code using it could also empty the list or set it to Nothing. [Guidelines for Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Plutonix 1. Would you move my code from Variations to Variation in this case or it has a sense as it is? 2. What if i would create collection class for Variation class and inherit from CollectionBase? Would it be collection class then?

Comment: a) No, I wouldnt.  Everytime you create a new Variation, you probably dont need/want a new collection as well.  b) I have no idea what these things are or how they are used so it is hard to say.  It sounds like you are striving for a Col Class but I have no idea why.  Those methods dont have to be used though, users can add/delete directly from Collection since it is public, so if there are rules and limitation to adding. For a Col Class, the article says **not** to use CollectionBase, but Collection(of T). Much depends on how it is used, as is, the code using it could not do For Each on it.

Comment: Think of a bunch of cars.  For that we need a Car class.  Then of course, a collection to store them.  In some cases, a List(of Car) might be all we need.  But, if the app is a car dealership, the cars is just part of the picture: there is also a collection of employees of various types.  So it might make sense to move logic related to the collections out of the Dealership biz object and into a Cars collection class and a Employees collection class.  Its not often you really need a Col Class, but one reason is to simplify managing multiple collections

Comment: @Plutonix is it good to say rather in current times we would use business objects rather than custom collections as existing collections are just enough? Would it be possible you to show some code based on your car example? Just would like to a look how this could look like to get the point. will mark as answer certainly.

Comment: That makes it sound like they went out of style.  Its more like a Biz object is more applicable more often.  Start writing custom controls and you may soon need one or two. The demo for [this CodeProject Article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework) has gobs of collection classes of varying degrees of sophistication.